# javascript date from utc to local time

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, utc, date-conversion

```
$("span[datetime]").each(function() {
    var me = $(this);
    var ms = me.data('utime') * 1000;
    dt = new Date(ms);

    me.attr('datetime', dt.toString());
});
```

utime is UNIX_TIMESTAMP from a datetime (UTC) let's say 1402355007 for the UTC datetime of 2014-06-10 00:03:27

let's say the user's OS settings are set to Amsterdam UTC+01:00

in the above example datetime attribute becomes "Tue Jun 10 2014 01:03:27 GMT+0200" and the jQuery.age plugin says "an hour ago" ... when it should say "now", it is an hour behind

any ideas how to tackle this issue?

Comment: Obviously you are not using user's local time in your above example since you already providing the `utime`. Why it would has the problem?

Comment: utime is the seconds from 1970... 1402355007 in UTC, now I want to display this time in user's local time zone ;) and as you can see dt.toString() already involves the user's time zone "Tue Jun 10 2014 01:03:27 GMT+0200"  => GMT+0200